# Reassembling fragments in a PCAP file

Tags: python, pcap

We have largish (100 MiB-3 GiB) PCAP files that have huge UDP datagrams that are heavily fragmented, and we need to process them in Python, preferably datagram-by-datagram without reading everything into memory first, due to the potential size of the files. I'm looking for a package that is capable of reading *and* reassembling IP packets. I've looked at `pypcapfile`, `dpkt`, and `scapy`. Of these, AFAICT only `scapy` reassembles fragments, but it requires reading the file entirely into memory first, and anyway the GPLv2 license is intolerable in our organization. Are there any *other* PCAP reading and processing packages out there that will decode and do fragment reassembly, preferably datagram-by-datagram?

Alternatively -- this is not a python question -- is there an OTS command-line tool that will reassemble packets from one PCAP to another? I tried `tshark` with `-r`, `-w`, and `-Y ip.flags.mf==0` or `-R ip.flags.mf==0` and so far no dice.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the last part, this may be the solution:

```
tshark -nlr $infile -qz "follow,tcp,raw,$stream" | tail -n +7 | sed 's/^\s\+//g' | xxd -r -p > ${outfile}.txt
```